# Change color of symbol and automatically apply shared style

Tags: sketch-app

I'm practicing creating a design system with Sketchapp. 
I already defined the shared style for text.[image]

The above shared style are: Black/Left/Regular/Large & Center & Right.
I wish to apply the same shared text style for the below, only change the color to primary. Is there a quick way to do this (also apply the primary share style), instead of go to each symbol and apply the Primary/Left/Regular/Large style?
I have tried to change the color using the color picker, but only the color changes, the shared styles did not update?

Answer (score 0):

Take your color swatches and create symbols out of them and then insert as a symbol into the type symbol. You should then be able to edit those colors in the inspector list. Your color symbols need to be the same sizes in order for them all to populate.

Comment: Here's an article I think will explain better than I can

Comment: Thanks but is there a link for that article?

Comment: Sorry thought it pasted. Here's one you can reference, there are others also you can find mainly on Medium.https://blog.desandoval.net/sketch-app-a-better-responsive-button-using-symbols-53df1b61a47a